# Selenium HtmlUnitDriver save Session ID or Cookies

Tags: cookies, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

How is it possible to save the session id or the cookies I need to stay logged in at a website after the login, when I'm using HtmlUnitDriver from Selenium 2.0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Enabling the cookies at first:

```
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);//enable cookies
```

Check out the [Cookies](http://ksblog.org/index.php?q=htmlunit-cookies-handling&id=49) it has some more info and extra code you might want to check out

Comment: What is webClient? You are confusing Selenium with HtmlUnit I believe.